# Access object values from moderatecontent result

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using the `moderatecontent` api to detect if images, videos or files contain specific inappropriate content. However, all currently works until I choose to specifically select a value from a key within the object the result returns.

My code I have used is below:

```js
var ajax_url = "https://api.moderatecontent.com/moderate/";
var image_url = "sample_face_2.jpg"; 
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

        console.log(xhttp.responseText)

    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", ajax_url + "?key=1234567890&url=" + image_url, true);
xhttp.send();
```

This logs to the console as:

```
{
    "url_classified": "sample_face_2.jpg",
    "rating_index": 1,
    "rating_letter": "e",
    "predictions": {
        "teen": 0.11751182222118,
        "everyone": 99.823732266668,
        "adult": 0.05875591111059
    },
    "rating_label": "everyone",
    "error_code": 0,
    "frame": 1
}
```

However, how can I specifically get the "adult" rating from the object it produces above?
I have attempted to use `this.adult` or `console.log(xhttp.responseText.predictions)` but these results either causes error or "undefined" when it prints to console.

I have also checked the Documentation but does not show how to retrieve these specific values from the object it returns.

https://moderatecontent.com/

Really appreciate if someone can help out!

Comment: See what you get when you do `console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText.predictions))` ?

Comment: Thankyou, that worked